# CloudFormation : How to refer to existing AWS Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What are the best ways to refer to Existing resources (Lambda, IAM Role, S3 bucket etc) when these are created manually from the console page?

Is it using
Import Existing resources and copy
Parameters
Custom Resources
or any other options

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a CloudFormation Stack from existing resources. As there are some following steps to do this thing.

- Open the AWS CloudFormation console.
- On the Stacks page, choose Create stack, and then choose With
  existing resources (import resources).
- Read the Import overview page for a list of things you're required to
  provide during this operation.

For more and detailed help this AWS UserGuide and Blog's will help you achieve it easily.

[Refer Existing Resources into a CloudFormation Stack](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/)

[Creating a stack from existing resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html)

Comment: Is it possible only through importing, no other way and is that the best possible way @Abdul Moeez

Comment: Yes, this is the best recommended way if you using a console but if the resources are created through YAML or JSON code. Then there is no need to import it, we just ref the exiting resources in YAML code. The resources which are created through console didn't refer to code as well.